# RGB to HEX conversion yield strange characters with output

Tags: c

I'm trying to solve this CodeWars kata: https://www.codewars.com/kata/513e08acc600c94f01000001/train/c

In my editor works fine, but in the CodeWars editor only pass the basics test.
Random tests show some unrecognized characters before the answer, and so the test couldn't pass.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int rgb(int r, int g, int b, char *output)
{
    int values[3] = {r,g,b};
    char temp[3] = "";
   
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
       // Check number range
       if(values[i] > 255)
       {
           values[i] = 255;
       }
       else if(values[i] < 0)
       {
           values[i] = 0;
       }
       
       // Save Hex number into temp string
       sprintf(temp,"%02X",values[i]);
       // Copy temp string into output
       strcat(output,temp);
    }
  
   return 0; 
}
```

And this is the screenshot of results:
[image: Results of kata]

Why could these strange characters appear?

Comment: You’re assuming `output` is initialized to be null-terminated empty C string. It isn’t. Hint: you can put several things in one `sprintf`

Comment: [strcpy](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcpy.htm) can be used instead of strcat to copy the string to the output.

Comment: @NickODell Not in this case, he is appending deliberately. He doesn't have to, but he is.

Comment: Additionally `output` must have sufficient storage to hold what you are attempting to place there. Since that part of the code is not shown, it will be up to you to verify.

Comment: Thanks to everyone. I solved it. I only used a sprintf call to put all answers in output and now it works. Thanks a lot.